# Java upgrade from 1.4 to 6

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, upgrade

I am using Jboss 2.4.11, if i upgrade JDK from 1.4 to 6 How is the jboss server going to handle the application?. What are the common things i should start investigating while i am in the process of the upgrade. I am looking at the Oracle's documentation and other posts in stackoverflow related to jdk 6 backwards compatibility with v1.4. My question is more specific towards using Jboss server. Also the application uses ejb 1.1

Comment: JBoss 2.4.11 is pretty old. In fact, it is 9 years old. I suggest testing your applications in a more recent version of JBoss.

Comment: Since there are multiple old things in my project I am considering upgrading only jdk version for now.

Comment: Right. But the thing is: you app may have unexpected behaviors due to the upgrade, same goes to the libraries in the web server. So, if you ask me, I'll go for a web server tested with jdk6

Comment: Thank you. i will evaluate it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recomment to move from one consistent system to another one. Even JBoss 4 needs a special version for JDK1.6. Java 5 brought MBeans rigth into the VM and older versions of JBoss used MBeans for configuration. As there must not be to MBean servers within a single VM this was a big issue, when migrated to java5. As EJB 1.1 is still supported I'd recomment to move at least to JBoss 4.2 as this is still kind of similar to older versions, while JBoss 7 is totally different.

The only thing that will really help you to get the migration a little bit smother are tests. At least quite a number of integration tests.

Comment: Thank you for the sugesstion. I will try and update the results here.